# I want to know what is a functionalities in my app require SMS and Call Log permissions?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I created an app and want to publish it on Google Play.

In order to work properly,My app uses following declared SMS and Call log permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

I'm using **"android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"** and **"android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"**
just To Know who is calling and use the caller's phone number to send a message .

My question is "What functionalities in My app require SMS and Call Log permissions?".

[image]

[image]